# Multithreading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, python-multithreading, release

thread lock is not working ...anything wrong with the code its triggering the thread 2 insted of lock the previous thread till its released

```
import threading
import time


# for lock
def xx():
    print("locking the thread")
    
    lock1.acquire()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("thraed locked")
    time.sleep(1)
    lock1.release()




def xx1():
    print("thread lock released")




lock1=threading.Lock()


tt1=threading.Thread(target=xx)

tt2=threading.Thread(target=xx1)

tt1.start()

tt2.start()
```

thread lock is not working properly.. if i use the join after the first thread start its working

Comment: are you thinking that `lock1.acquire()` will block the execution of tt2 ? if so that is not correct. if want to secure(i.e no two thread update them at same time) the resource, then in xx1, you would have like this `with lock1:
        print("thread lock released")`

Answer (score 0):

```
import threading
import time

lock1=threading.Lock()

# for lock
def xx():
    print("locking the thread")
    
    lock1.acquire()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("thraed locked")
    time.sleep(1)
    lock1.release()

def xx1():
    lock1.acquire()
    print("thread lock released")
    lock1.release()

tt1=threading.Thread(target=xx)
tt2=threading.Thread(target=xx1)

tt1.start()
tt2.start()
```